# facebook login with python request

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x

I am using folllowing code to login to facebook and it works perfectly but every time i use this code i send a Notification

> Your account was logged in to from an unrecognised browser or device.
>   Please review this login now.

I have also marked to remember that browser in facebook but i keep on comming again and again.

I think there is something wrong with my header.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def facebook_login(mail, pwd):
    headers = {
        'host':'m.facebook.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }

    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get('https://m.facebook.com/', headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    f = open('test.html', 'w')
    f.write(bs.prettify())
    f.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    action_url = soup.find('form', id='login_form')['action']
    inputs = soup.find('form', id='login_form').findAll('input', {'type': ['hidden', 'submit']})
    post_data = {input.get('name'): input.get('value')  for input in inputs}
    post_data['email'] = mail
    post_data['pass'] = pwd.upper()
    z = session.post(action_url, data=post_data, headers=headers  , allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: Would you like to use `Selenium` for this?

Comment: _“I think there is something wrong with my header”_ – no, there is something wrong with what you are trying to do in general. Using any automated tools to interact with their site is against Facebook’s ToS.